# Bulk insert using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, bulkinsert

I have a query which is working fine:

```
BULK INSERT ZIPCodes 
FROM  'e:\5-digit Commercial.csv' 
WITH 
( 
     FIRSTROW = 2 ,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' 
)
```

but now I want to create a stored procedure for it.

I have written below code to make its stored procedure:

```
create proc dbo.InsertZipCode
@filepath varchar(500)='e:\5-digit Commercial.csv'
as
begin
BULK INSERT ZIPCodes 
FROM  @filepath 
WITH 
( 
     FIRSTROW = 2 ,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' 
)
end
```

but its showing error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure
>   InsertZipCode, Line 6 Incorrect syntax
>   near '@filepath'.
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Procedure
>   InsertZipCode, Line 7 Incorrect syntax
>   near the keyword 'with'. If this
>   statement is a common table
>   expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or
>   a change tracking context clause, the
>   previous statement must be terminated
>   with a semicolon.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong and what I can do to make it work in stored procedure.

Thanks

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your stored procedure code - the point is: the `BULK INSERT` command cannot accept a file name as a variable.

This does work:

```
BULK INSERT ZIPCodes 
FROM  'e:\5-digit Commercial.csv' 
WITH
```

but this never works - within a stored proc or not:

```
DECLARE @filename VARCHAR(255)
SET @filename = 'e:\5-digit Commercial.csv' 

BULK INSERT ZIPCodes 
FROM @filename
WITH
```

So you just cannot do it this way, unfortunately. You could consider building up your `BULK INSERT` statement as a string (with a fixed file name) and then execute it as dynamic SQL - but I don't really see any other solution.

```
DECLARE @filepath nvarchar(500)
SET @filepath = N'e:\5-digit Commercial.csv'

DECLARE @bulkinsert NVARCHAR(2000)

SET @bulkinsert = 
       N'BULK INSERT ZIPCodes FROM ''' + 
       @filepath + 
       N''' WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'')'

EXEC sp_executesql @bulkinsert
```

Comment: thanks i have already done it as a string and run it using exec but i thought that there may be some other solutions. thanks a lot.

Comment: marc_s but can I execute  EXEC sp_executesql @bulkinsert from procedure? so my C# interface will call my SQL  procedure , pass parameters (filepath, table name) into, and its will create string  and call dynamic SQL ?

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative to dynamic SQL if you have access to the SQLCmd exe.

The SqlCmd utility allows you to pass string replacement variables using the -v argument.

You can use a template variable named "filepath" which will be replaced when you execute the script via the cmdline.

The SQL script would look like:

```
BULK INSERT ZIPCodes 
FROM  '$(filepath)' 
WITH 
( 
     FIRSTROW = 2 ,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' 
)
end
```

You would then execute the script from a commandline using something like the following:

```
sqlcmd -b -S SERVER\INSTANCEHERE -E -i "PATH\FILENAMEHERE.Sql" -v FilePath = "e:\5-digit Commercial.csv" -s "|"
```

The important part of the example is the -v argument:

```
-v FilePath = "e:\5-digit Commercial.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

You just try it out, I think you need to upload this CSV file directly to the 'E' drive. For that you need to have admin rights, I think, or ask someone who is in database administration.

```
create procedure dbo.InsertZipCode
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
 BULK
   INSERT ZIPCodes from 'e:\5-digit Commercial.csv'
WITH
(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
END
```

Answer (score -5):

```
create PROC TestInsert
    (
      @stuName NVARCHAR(50) ,
      @XmlData XML
    )
AS
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRY 
            INSERT  INTO dbo.Test_Student
                    ( stuName 
                    )
            VALUES  ( @stuName
                    );
            DECLARE @id BIGINT;
            SET @id = ( SELECT  SCOPE_IDENTITY()
                      ); 
            INSERT  INTO dbo.Test_Qual
                    ( stuid ,
                      stuclass ,
                      InstituteId ,
                      obtmark ,
                      totalmark ,
                      per
                    )
                    SELECT  @id ,
                            col.value('stuclass[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS stuclass ,
                            col.value('InstituteId[1]', 'int') AS InstituteId ,
                            col.value('obtmark[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS obtmark ,
                            col.value('totalmark[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS totalmark ,
                            col.value('per[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') AS per
                    FROM    @XmlData.nodes('Parent/child') AS Doc ( col );  

            SELECT  @id AS RegisIdNUH ,
                    1 AS Flag ,
                    'Save' AS Msg
            FROM    dbo.Test_Student R
            WHERE   R.stuid = @id;

        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT  0 AS Flag ,
                    'Some Error occur' AS Msg;
            ROLLBACK;
        END CATCH;
    END;
```

Comment: What in the world is this?