# How to prevent SQL injection in dynamic sql for bulk insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-injection, bulkinsert, bulk

I'm using dynamic SQL for bulk insert with a parameter ([Bulk insert using stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050790/bulk-insert-using-stored-procedure/4051325#comment78638809_4051325)).

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000) = 'BULK INSERT TblValues FROM ''' + @FileName + ''' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR ='','', ROWTERMINATOR =''\n'' )';
EXEC(@sql);
```

But... How to avoid SQL injection?

Comment: Take a look at sp_executesql https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql

Comment: @Leonidas199x - sp_executesql works with parameters, and bulk insert doesn't support parameters in 'FROM' clause

Comment: My bad, wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `QUOTENAME` to surround the file name in single quotes:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000) = 'BULK INSERT TblValues FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@FileName,'''') + ' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR ='','', ROWTERMINATOR =''\n'' )';
EXEC (@sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to retrieve the file name versus pass it in... something like

```
DECLARE @fileLocation VARCHAR(128) = '\\some\folder\location'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#FileNames') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #FileNames
CREATE TABLE #FileNames(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,subdirectory nvarchar(512)
    ,depth int
    ,isfile bit)
INSERT #FileNames(subdirectory,depth,isfile)
EXEC xp_dirtree @fileLocation, 1, 1
```

Then, in #FileNames will be all the files in that directory (where isfile = 1 of course). Then you can simply query the file name(s) from the temp table.