text file lines → table rows via existing stored procedure that inserts a single row
Been struggling with this one. Long story short I have a problem where we need to read a file at different times throughout the month provided by the client. The file can be a few hundred lines, or over a million lines. I've searched and nothing quite hits the stored procedure call issue (I've seen using executemany, etc)
For each line, I need to read the line contents (delimited), and write the contents to a database. I currently have ALL of it working. The issue is timing. I took this out of an interface engine because it took 1 hr to read roughly 5000 lines. I created this application in python with the hopes to significantly speed up this process.
My ask is: what would be the best way to "multi-thread" this to increase the speed? Basically I need to read the file as fast as possible and get the data inserted into the DB as fast as possible. The bolded section below is the part I'd like to somehow multi-thread and have execute multiple at a time.
def ReadMetaDataFile (srcFile, fileDelimiter, clientID, mysqlCnx):
    functionResponse = ''
    path, filename = os.path.split(srcFile)

    try:
        with open(srcFile, 'r') as delimitedFile:
            fileReader = csv.DictReader(delimitedFile, delimiter=fileDelimiter)
            #next(fileReader, None)
            
            if(mysqlCnx and mysqlCnx.is_connected()):
                cursor = mysqlCnx.cursor()
                for row in fileReader:
                    **rowArgs = (clientID, row['FILENAME'], '', row['DATA_FORMAT'], 1)
                    cursor.callproc('sp_InsertMetaData', rowArgs)
                    mysqlCnx.commit()**
                cursor.close()
                mysqlCnx.close()
                functionResponse = "MetaData File Loaded Successfully"
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        functionResponse =  "Error processing MySQL SPROC call: " + str(err)
    except (mysql.connector.Error, IOError) as err:
        functionResponse =  "Error connecting to MySQL in function: " + str(err)
    except Exception as err:
        functionResponse =  "Exception Found in function: " + str(err)
    finally:
        mysqlCnx.close()
        return functionResponse

--UPDATE
I've tried several different things and at this point I'm just setting up the sproc calls(not actually executing) and it's taking over 20 mins to read 20k rows from a file. Having millions of rows in some files this is simply too long. Any suggestions please.
def ReadMetaDataFile (srcFile, fileDelimiter, clientID, engine):
    functionResponse = ''
    path, filename = os.path.split(srcFile)

    try:
        query = 'CALL sp_InsertMetaData (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
        with open(srcFile, 'r') as delimitedFile:
            fileReader = csv.DictReader(delimitedFile, delimiter=fileDelimiter)
            conn = engine.raw_connection()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            for row in fileReader:
                rowArgs = (clientID, row['FILENAME'], '', row['DATA_FORMAT'], row['SOURCE_SYSTEM_NAME'], row['CONFIDENTIALITY_CODE'], row['STATUS'], row['DOCUMENT_TYPE_SOURCE_SYSTEM'], row['DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID'], row['DOCUMENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION'], row['DATE_OF_SERVICE'], row['DOCUMENT_ID'], row['SOURCE_CREATED_DATE'], row['SOURCE_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE'], row['TIMEZONE'], row['MRNSOURCE_SYSTEM'], row['PATIENT_MRN'], row['MEMBER_NBR'], row['PATIENT_LAST_NAME'], row['PATIENT_FIRST_NAME'], row['PATIENT_MIDDLE_NAME'], row['GENDER'], row['PATIENT_DATE_OF_BIRTH'], row['ENCOUNTER_SOURCE'], row['ENCOUNTER_ID'], row['ENCOUNTER_TYPE'], row['ADMIT_TIME'], row['DISCHARGE_TIME'], row['FACILITY_NAME'], row['FACILITY_SOURCE_SYSTEM'], row['PROVIDER_TYPE'], row['PROVIDER_SOURCE_SYSTEM'], row['PROVIDER_IDENTIFIER'], row['PROVIDER_LAST_NAME'], row['PROVIDER_FIRST_NAME'], row['PROVIDER_MIDDLE_NAME'], row['PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL'], row['PROVIDER_SPECIALTY'], 1)
                cursor.callproc("sp_InsertMetaData", rowArgs)
            #conn.commit()
            cursor.close()

            functionResponse = "MetaData File Loaded Successfully"


Your code is slow because you are calling .callproc() once for each row to insert, and each .callproc() results in two round-trips to the database. (One to set the parameter values and another to actually CALL the stored procedure.)
You will probably get much better performance if you upload all rows to a temporary table and then use another stored procedure to loop through the temporary table and call the existing stored procedure. After the temporary table has been populated, all subsequent processing happens on the server. If the temporary table is called tmp_tbl the new stored procedure would look something like this:
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_InsertMyDataBatch`()
   MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE new_id INT;
DECLARE new_txt VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id, txt FROM tmp_tbl;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
OPEN cur1;
read_loop: LOOP
   FETCH cur1 INTO new_id, new_txt;
   IF done THEN
     LEAVE read_loop;
   END IF;
   CALL sp_InsertMyData(new_id, new_txt);
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur1;
END


To reproduce your issue I've prepared file with 5000 lines and tried to read it line by line. It took 0.07 s, so I'd assume that your bottleneck is inserting the data in the database. Try to use batch insert for that kind of operation. I'm pretty sure it'll be enough for your task.

Does batch insert work with stored procedure calls?
Also, I guess I'd want to fully explain, many of the files will be at least 30k, the largest I've seen is 2.5M. These are the ones I need to ensure don't take hours to process.

As far as I can see, yes, it works.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050790/bulk-insert-using-stored-procedure
The same operation with 2.5M file (but without printing to console) took 1.24 s on my machine. You can also use async with aiofiles.open to improve performance, but I'd recommend to start with optimizing db queries.

Appreciate the response Victor. Can you show me what you'd change in my "for" loop?
I tried to update as you've suggested and I've had a 500k file running for about 30 mins now. I will say the stored procedure is rather simple. It does basic inserts with some super minor validation.

Unfortunately, I don't have possibility to prepare stored procedure for you as I don't have proper environment to debug it. But I can actually show you how I'd do it without the procedure, but using something like sqlalchemy. Is it important for you to use a stored procedure in this situation?

Unfortunately it is. There is some basic validation in that stored procedure. However, I would be open to potentially switching to import (INSERT) into another sort of hold table and then run the row through the stored procedure, just need to make some minor updates there. I'm just looking for how to get that for loop sproc calls to execute as fast as possible.
